# Автовоспроизвидение видео в Ios Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, видео, safari

Делаю стриминг сервис для вебинаров. Когда пользователь заходит на страницу, он видит таймер и когда таймер подходит к концу - мне надо запустить видео. В Хроме все работает, а вот в Safari видео показывается, но не проигрывается.

В Safari для Mac есть настройка, что бы разрешить автопроигрывание, а вот в ios safari не могу такого найти

Помогите, если кто то сталкивался с таким

Comment: Ваш код нам самим додумать, я так полагаю?

Comment: при чем тут код? это настройка браузера

Comment: "Это не мой код не работает, это все браузер". Да, яблочные браузеры крайне капризны, но автовоспроизведение в них возможно. Чтобы понять, что у Вас не так - нужен код. А если вопрос заключается только в том, где у мобильного Safari настройка, запрещающая автовоспроизведение, (зачем только тогда нам вся эта предыстория?), то отвечу - конкретно для Safari ее нет.

Comment: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/ настроек нет. Есть условия при которых автоплей работает